# Passing one message to just one messagelistener with Spring data redis

Tags: java, redis, publish-subscribe, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I have service in place which monitors key expiry topic `__keyevent@*__:expired` in redis. I am running 3 instance of the service. Which means 3 message listener.
The `RedisKeyExpirationListener` setup based on the suggestion in this solution https://developpaper.com/implementation-code-of-expired-key-monitoring-in-redis-cluster/

The above solution suggests using Distributed redis lock to make sure there is parallel processing i.e. same event not being processed again by a different node. Is there a different solution to make sure that Redis passes a event to just 1 node, to have true parallel processing across the 3 nodes rather than same event being processed with different nodes.

I know how to implement distributed lock with redis but want to understand if there are precise settings to enable or make sure the event is sent to only 1 active messagelistener and not all the keyexpirationlisteners ??

Comment: In Redis Cluster, pub/sub for key events will not be broadcast outside those subscribed to the node: https://redis.io/topics/notifications#events-in-a-cluster so this may not be an issue.

Comment: Well I am trying to make sure it is picked by just 1 node (among the ones running the listener)  and not all node. I am already aware that this will be broadcast only to the registered listeners.